# STM32F10x Flash size mismatch

Tags: cmsis, stm32f1

I have a bunch of Blue Pill boards I'm re-animating (ye olde chippe shortage, y'know). Attacking them with stm32flash reports a flash size of 128 kBytes. On the other hand, 0x1FFFF7E0 contains 0x40, indicating 64 kBytes of flash as per ST's RM0008 reference manual.

Now, which of these is correct? if it's the former, how can the code running on the board discover that fact?

Comment: Are they genuine STM32 parts as labeled by the silkscreen, or are they something like the CS32 knockoff MCUs? :)

Comment: They look genuine, and a test program that's been reported to find these knock-offs didn't see any problem either.

Comment: Hrm, interesting. I've also noticed similar questions about the actual flash size on my F103C8s and actually flashed programs that required more than 64k flash without issue. I'm also genuinely confused :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, some or all of that extra flash is present and may or may not work.

https://community.st.com/s/question/0D53W000017QxPqSAK/stm32f10x-flash-size-mismatch